# Lombok @Wither/@With Inheritance (super-/sub-classes)

Tags: java, lombok

Please suggest how to use `@Wither`/`@With` when inheritance applied.

I have an abstract class `Parent` and concrete `Child`. `Child` is supposed to be immutable. Putting `@Wither` on both gives me two errors:

- The constructor Child(String) is undefined
- The type Child must implement the inherited abstract method
  Parent.withA(String)

```java
@Value
@Wither
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder
abstract class Parent {
    String a;
}

@Value
@Wither
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
class Child extends Parent {
    String b;
}
```

I'd be happy to just remove `@Wither` and use the builder methods, but I'm refactoring a public library (trying to optimize the model classes) and I don't want compilation errors on my clients.

I also found this issue that explains the second error. But the logic of the intention is not clear https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/945

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lombok is an annotation processor. Those run on each compilation unit (i.e. Java file) and do not have access to information from other compilation units. That means that Lombok cannot know anything about the contents of class `Parent` when processing `Child`.

So when generating the code for `Child`, Lombok does not know what wither methods are inherited from `Parent`. Consequently, it cannot generate an implementation for the abstract `withA()` from `Parent`.

A second problem is that the wither methods need a constructor that has all fields as parameter, including those from the superclass. That is also impossible to generate for Lombok due to the aforementioned limitation.

To make a long story short: `@Wither` does not work well with inheritance. I suggest putting it only on `Parent` and implementing it manually for `Child`.

Another option is to put `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)` on both classes and then use `instance.toBuilder().a("newValue").build()`.