# Lombok @With annotation not working working on inheritance

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, lombok

I am creating inmutable classes with inheritance but whenever I try to use `@With` in a Child class attribute, I receive an error because the constructor that Lombok uses in the `@With` does not include the parent attributes. Example:

**Parent class**

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
public abstract class Order extends SelfValidating<Order> {

  @Valid
  @NotBlank(message = "orderNumber must not be empty")
  private final String orderNumber;
  private final String orderId;
  private final String externalOrderId;

  protected Order(String orderNumber, String orderId, String externalOrderId) {
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    this.orderId = orderId;
    this.externalOrderId = externalOrderId;
  }
}
```

**Child class**

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Value
public class ChildOrder extends Order {

  @NotBlank(message = "Invoice number should not be blank")
  @Valid
  @With
  String invoiceNumber;

  @Builder
  public ChildOrder(
      String orderNumber,
      String orderId,
      String externalOrderId,
      String invoiceNumber) {
    super(orderNumber, orderId, externalOrderId);
    this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    super.validateSelf();
  }
}
```

This is throwing an exception when I run the code:

```
error: constructor ChildOrder in class ChildOrder cannot be applied to given types;
  @With
  ^
  required: String,String,String,String
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This is because the Lombok's implementation of `@With` is as follow:

```java
  public ChildOrder withInvoiceNumber(@NotBlank(message = "Invoice number should not be blank") @Valid String invoiceNumber) {
    return this.invoiceNumber == invoiceNumber ? this : new ChildOrder(invoiceNumber);
  }
```

But the constructor `new ChildOrder(invoiceNumber)` does not exist, since I am using a `super` to include parent's attributes.

So far, I implemented the `With` pattern manually and I am including all the attributes for the parent, but I would like to know if there is a way to keep using Lombok for this?

Comment: related: [how to Call super constructor in Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29740078/1371329)

Comment: `@With` was `@Wither` before, and here's a similar question: [Lombok @Wither Inheritance (super-/sub- classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761054/lombok-wither-inheritance-super-sub-classes)