# Lombok @With sets inherited fields on the clone to null. How do I make it copy to work?

Tags: java, lombok

I'm trying to set up cloning with Lombok using its `@With` annotation, but I ran into a problem where it sets inherited fields to null. To demonstrate, say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
abstract class Person {
    protected String name;
    protected Integer age;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@With
@Getter
class Employee extends Person {
    protected String id;
    
    @Builder
    public Employee(String name, Integer age, String id) {
        super(name, age);
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I try doing:

```
var template = Employee.builder().name("John Smith").age(20).build();
var clone = template.withId("ABC123");
```

both `clone.name` and `clone.age` return null. Is this construct allowed? How do I make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok @Wither Inheritance (super-/sub- classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761054/lombok-wither-inheritance-super-sub-classes)

Comment: @JanRieke Thanks. I stumbled upon the `toBuilder` after posting this question, and it kind of accomplished what I'm after, albeit less satisfactory. I'm guessing the situation hasn't changed since your answer, and the best option for now is to use the `toBuilder`?

Comment: No changes in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Lombok @With doesn't support inherited fields.
However, I did find passable a workaround using the `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)` annotation on both classes. This way, instead of calling the `someInstance.withSomeField(xyz)` method,
you call a `someInstance.toBuilder().someField(xyz).build()`.
This does preserve all of base class fields and creates a new instance. While being longer, it still looks pretty clear and self documenting code.
consider this example:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public static class Animal {
    String color;
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public static class Cat extends Animal {
    String name;
}
```

now you can call the toBuilder like this:

```
    Cat catKoko = Cat.builder().name("Koko").color("mixed").build(); //name=Koko , color=mixed
    Cat catLolik = catKoko.toBuilder().name("Lolik").build(); //name=Lolik , color=mixed
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce using your code as it is erroneous, fix the following errors and you get your code to work:

**Compilation errors:**

- You cannot pass `int` to `String`. You call `.age(20)` but it is defined as `String age`.
- The very same for `id` as above.
- The `Person` class should be `abstract class`, not `class abstract`.
- The full-args constructor of `Person` is undefined, so `Employee` doesn't compile. Annotate `Person` with `@AllArgsConstructor`.
- Due to the inheritance and non-args constructor in the parent class, you must remove both `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor` placed on `Employee`.

**Warnings:**

- Lombok requires for `@With` annotation a base default constructor in the `Employee` class - you must define it manually: `public Employee(int id)`. Read the specification of the `@With` annotation at https://projectlombok.org/features/With.

  > The `@With` relies on a constructor for all fields in order to do its work. If this constructor does not exist, your `@With` annotation will result in a compile time error message.

The code starts to work after fixing all the above. Next time, please, prepare at least a compilable snippet.

```
@Test
void testWith() {
    var template = Employee.builder().name("John Smith").age(20).build();
    var clone = template.withId(23);
    assertThat(clone.getId(), is(23));
}
```

Comment: I have now corrected the sample code. However, even with all the corrections done, the problem is still there. What you miss in your test is to check the `age` and/or `name` not the `id` which is defined in the `Employee` class. The problem is that those inherited fields are left empty after cloning.

Answer (score 0):

@With doesn't seem to work with inheritance.
As a workaround, you can try this code:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
abstract class Person {
    protected String name;

    protected Integer age;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Employee extends Person {
    protected String id;

    @Builder
    public Employee(String name, Integer age, String id) {
        super(name, age);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Employee withId(String id) {
        return this.id == id ? this : new Employee(name, age, id);
    }

}
```

It will work, but, unfortunately, you have to implement "**withId**" method yourself.